# Export variable to parent process

Tags: fish

When writing fish scripts, I'd like to be able to factor out common code into separate scripts. Something akin to this:

```
#! /usr/bin/fish

fish setup.sh

// Put rest of my code here.
```

but, as far as I can see, there's no way to export variables to parent processes, only children. Children can be done with `set --export`; is there a way to make variables visible to parents? I understand that the mechanisms are probably not similar, but it would be nice.

Comment: This is where you use [the `source` command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#source) -- all changes are done in the *current* shell, not a child shell. It is impossible for a child shell to alter the environment of its parent.

Comment: I believe the convention for fish scripts is to use a `.fish` extension, but of course that's up to you.

Comment: @glennjackman thanks! I've been messing around with `source`, and it seems to be what I want. Although it's not a macro (set --local doesn't work), so I'm not sure what it's doing internally. Also, I use `.fish`, just wasn't sure if that's normal so I changed it to `.sh` in my example.

Answer (score 2):

The UNIX process model makes it impossible for a process to affect the environment of any other process. This isn't a limitation of `fish`. The solution is to use the `source` command so the statements in *setup.sh* are executed in the context of the current process. If *setup.sh* is not a fish script the usual solution is to have it write `export VAR=val` statements to stdout then do `setup.sh | source -`.

Comment: It would be possible if the commands called in scripts were threads instead of separate processes, as threads share memory blocks. But obviously that is not how commands are programmed, and maybe for good reason it's not an option.